# How can I filter a table based in two values at same time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I want to filter one dataframe if two other values are not present in the other dataframe. Both dataframes share the name of the columns.

For example, dataframe A has:

```
col1,col2
1     5
-10   15
6     7
```

and dataframe B has:

```
col1,col2
6     7
-10   15
-1    5
```

So in this example, I would like to pick the value pair in A and see if it is present in B.

First row of A has value pair `1,5` and since `1,5` is not present in B that row would be excluded from A.
Second and third row of A has value `-10,15` and `6,7`, and since both are present in B I would like to keep them.

So the desired output of the filtered table A would be:

```
col1,col2
-10   15
6     7
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: One of the first things I tried was a merge, but the resulting dataframe was actually bigger than the original. Since merge and merging 101 topic was suggested, I will add the real dataframes here.

Dataframe A have latitude, longitude and id columns (id is not the index). It has 363 rows:

```
    id       lat        lon
0   0   -33.252192  -70.765291
1   1   -33.224300  -70.780249
2   2   -33.251651  -70.797289
3   3   -33.298574  -70.770133
4   4   -33.214315  -70.787822
... ... ... ...
358 499 -33.227614  -70.770126
359 501 -33.299217  -70.770685
360 502 -33.191476  -70.801492
361 503 -33.239037  -70.780278
362 504 -33.263893  -70.762674
```

Dataframe B has 73096 rows and it also has and id, latitude and longitude. I'm putting here only lat and lon.

```
        lat        lon
1   -33.260415  -70.713767
2   -33.461718  -70.853525
3   -33.258741  -70.638032
4   -33.544858  -70.578624
8   -33.535512  -70.574188
... ... ...
97724   -33.451817  -70.847999
97725   -33.452225  -70.846520
97726   -33.450841  -70.841494
97729   -33.461407  -70.856090
97730   -33.457633  -70.822085
```

So I want to see if the lat,lon pair in A is present in B and if not then exclude it from A.

When I do A.merge(B) I get a dataframe that is 1108 rows long.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Something like `df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on=['col1','col2'], right_on=['col1','col2'])`.

(To help you remember, the naming of these arguments comes from an inner join in database terminology)

Answer (score 0):

A simple merge will do

```
df_out = dfA.merge(dfB)
```

Output

```
   col1  col2
0   -10    15
1     6     7
```

`df.merge` does an inner join by default.